# Kylin build is failed at 3rd step

Tags: hive, kylin

I am new to Kylin,I create kylin model and cube by following url,

http://kylin.apache.org/

initially it is successfull,again i created new cube for the same model,at that time cube build is failed at 3rd step as,

```
#3 Step Name: Extract Fact Table Distinct Columns
```

actually i have some duplicated rows,so i deleted those rows in hive and i did sync kylin tables with hive tables.But that is not completing that 3rd step.I gone through the logs,i find the following error,

```
2016-12-29 11:50:45,421 ERROR [IPC Server handler 18 on 46096] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1482297779079_0128_m_000000_0 - exited : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.steps.FactDistinctHiveColumnsMapper.putRowKeyToHLL(FactDistinctHiveColumnsMapper.java:179)
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.steps.FactDistinctHiveColumnsMapper.map(FactDistinctHiveColumnsMapper.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)

2016-12-29 11:50:45,421 INFO [IPC Server handler 18 on 46096] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1482297779079_0128_m_000000_0: Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.steps.FactDistinctHiveColumnsMapper.putRowKeyToHLL(FactDistinctHiveColumnsMapper.java:179)
    at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.steps.FactDistinctHiveColumnsMapper.map(FactDistinctHiveColumnsMapper.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
```

anybody please share any idea how to solve this one.what is cardinality means in kylin data sources.

Comment: Can you try once again by clearing logs

Comment: I deleted old one.I created new one just now, that one also  have the same error at same stage.I am not able to find what is the cause.....please    give me any solution for this.It is a bit emergency for me.

Comment: can you provide me any documentation for how to create two or more kylin cubes in one model,any precautions we have to take before and after model and cube creations in kylin.Any Guidelines on how to sync hive and kylin after changes made in hive tables also.

Comment: Hello buddy subsrcibe to Kylin Mailing list and post your exception with screenshots.
Writing to the list                    user@kylin.apache.org
Subscription address            user-subscribe@kylin.apache.org
Digest subscription address    user-digest-subscribe@kylin.apache.org
Unsubscription addresses    user-unsubscribe@kylin.apache.org
Getting help with the list            user-help@kylin.apache.org

Comment: can u please tell to whom i have post my problem.............I tried with user and user-subscribe but they are saying that is not proper one.

Comment: anybody please suggest me how to solve this one.If this is not the right place for this question please provide me proper location where i have to post.Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 means what are the reasons for this type exception.

Comment: Your problem looks like this one: http://apache-kylin.74782.x6.nabble.com/jira-Created-KYLIN-2326-ERROR-ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException-1-td6774.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion,it is working for me.Thank you so much.Now I have some other problem,Now kylin is not sync with my hive tables incremental data.how to do that one.anybody have any idea please give me suggest me.

Comment: i followed the specified kylin documentation but it's not refreshing.Anybody please share me proper steps for refreshing kylin cubes.need to sync with hive tables.

Comment: if i am using date column in refreshment settings then my fact table is not showing anything when i used select command.Is it correct or not.